# Liquibase + Spring Data: How to create entities from JPA

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, liquibase

Is there possibility to create Liquibase scripts from @Entity declaration?

What I want?
When I run 'gradle diff`I suppouse liquibase check there is no table`Owner`on database, and create record in`changelog` file, then based on this record create table in the database.

I try to use this lib:
https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase-hibernate/wiki

**build.gradle:**

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.liquibase:liquibase-gradle-plugin:2.0.2"
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.2.2.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.8.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
    id "org.liquibase.gradle" version "2.0.2"
}

apply plugin: 'org.liquibase.gradle'

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    implementation 'org.liquibase:liquibase-core'
    runtimeOnly 'javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api'
    compile group: 'io.springfox', name: 'springfox-swagger2', version: swaggerVersion
    compile group: 'io.springfox', name: 'springfox-swagger-ui', version: swaggerVersion
    runtimeOnly 'mysql:mysql-connector-java'
    liquibaseRuntime 'org.liquibase:liquibase-core'
    liquibaseRuntime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java'
    liquibaseRuntime('org.liquibase.ext:liquibase-hibernate5:3.8')
    liquibaseRuntime('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter')
    liquibaseRuntime('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
}


liquibase {
    activities {
        main {
            driver 'com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver'
            url 'jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/homebudget'
            username 'user'
            password 'pass'
            changeLogFile 'src/main/resources/db/db.changelog-master.xml'
            defaultSchemaName 'homebudget'
            logLevel 'debug'
            changeLogFile 'src/main/resources/db/db.changelog-master.xml'
            referenceUrl 'hibernate:spring:com.homebudget.domain?dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect&hibernate.physical_naming_strategy=org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy&hibernate.implicit_naming_strategy=org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringImplicitNamingStrategy'
        }
    }
}
```

In my project I have Entity:
`com.homebudget.domain.Owner`

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
public class Owner extends BaseEntity {
    private String name;
}
```

When I run `gradle diff` I had message:

```
Reference Database: null @ hibernate:spring:pl.homebudget.domain?dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect&hibernate.physical_naming_strategy=org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy&hibernate.implicit_naming_strategy=org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringImplicitNamingStrategy (Default Schema: HIBERNATE)
Comparison Database: user@172.21.0.1 @ jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/homebudget (Default Schema: homebudget)
Compared Schemas: HIBERNATE -> homebudget
Product Name:
     Reference:   'Hibernate'
     Target: 'MySQL'
Product Version:
     Reference:   '5.4.9.Final'
     Target: '8.0.18'
Missing Catalog(s): NONE
Unexpected Catalog(s): NONE
Changed Catalog(s): 
     HIBERNATE
          name changed from 'HIBERNATE' to 'homebudget'
Missing Column(s): NONE
Unexpected Column(s): 
     homebudget.DATABASECHANGELOG.AUTHOR
     homebudget.DATABASECHANGELOG.COMMENTS
     homebudget.DATABASECHANGELOG.CONTEXTS
     homebudget.DATABASECHANGELOG.DATEEXECUTED
     homebudget.DATABASECHANGELOG.DEPLOYMENT_ID
     homebudget.DATABASECHANGELOG.DESCRIPTION
     homebudget.DATABASECHANGELOG.EXECTYPE
     homebudget.DATABASECHANGELOG.FILENAME
     homebudget.DATABASECHANGELOG.ID
     homebudget.DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK.ID
     homebudget.DATABASECHANGELOG.LABELS
     homebudget.DATABASECHANGELOG.LIQUIBASE
     homebudget.DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK.LOCKED
     homebudget.DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK.LOCKEDBY
     homebudget.DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK.LOCKGRANTED
     homebudget.DATABASECHANGELOG.MD5SUM
     homebudget.DATABASECHANGELOG.ORDEREXECUTED
     homebudget.DATABASECHANGELOG.TAG
Changed Column(s): NONE
Missing Foreign Key(s): NONE
Unexpected Foreign Key(s): NONE
Changed Foreign Key(s): NONE
Missing Index(s): NONE
Unexpected Index(s): 
     PRIMARY UNIQUE  ON homebudget.DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK(ID)
Changed Index(s): NONE
Missing Primary Key(s): NONE
Unexpected Primary Key(s): 
     PRIMARY on homebudget.DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK(ID)
Changed Primary Key(s): NONE
Missing Sequence(s): NONE
Unexpected Sequence(s): NONE
Changed Sequence(s): NONE
Missing Table(s): NONE
Unexpected Table(s): 
     DATABASECHANGELOG
     DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK
Changed Table(s): NONE
Missing Unique Constraint(s): NONE
Unexpected Unique Constraint(s): NONE
Changed Unique Constraint(s): NONE
Missing View(s): NONE
Unexpected View(s): NONE
Changed View(s): NONE
19:52:21.564 INFO  [liquibase.integration.commandline.Main]: Liquibase command 'diff' was executed successfully.
```

Comment: from liquibase-hibernate documentation you see that hbm2java is bad in production when the plugin is using it to help detecting differencies. If you don't you to many entities, perhaps it is better to do it by hand.